# Copy all GPOs (with links?) from domain to domain

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to copy the GPOs that are set up in a domain to another one - just to save a lot of configuring. The domains OUs are identical - except from domain name and machine names.

While searching for a solution for this I have come across some info that refers to some folder with some samples (%programfiles%\Gpmc\Scripts), but I can't locate that folder.

Does anyone have a nice answer or guide on how to copy all GPOs from one domain to another?

Comment: Why don't you simply export the GPO to a `.CAB` file and import the file on the other domain?

Comment: What does the `Export` and `Import` built in to group policy management not do for you (I know it does not do some things, i just want you to explicitly say what they are, just in case)

Answer (score 0):

I know that's the very old topic, but for those who would find the question, there is an answer:

These scripts are no longer packaged with Group Policy Management console in Server 2008/2008R2 or Server 2012.  Microsoft however has released these scripts for download to be used with any of the later versions of the Windows Operating system.  To download these scripts please view the following TechNet website:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14536